# Extract author affiliations with pubmed api

Tags: javascript, pubmed

I want to extract the affiliations (specifically country information) for just the first and last authors of a particular paper  using the pubmed api. Using eutils esummary search you can include the [ad] affiliation tag e.g. Australia[ad] to find all papers where ANY of the authors are Australian, but how would I restrict the search so just first or last are Australian. It seems from other answers on SO you can do with python or R but I can see how this is done making api requests from within a javascipt app.

Comment: Are you able to supply a link to the SO answers that do what you want using python/R?

Comment: Theres a few such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398935/using-rentrez-to-parse-out-author-and-affiliation-from-pubmed but i seems they use rentrez rather than the eutils api.